# Unable to loop through the Min attribute of HTML Date picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on something in which I should be able to choose the date with having a 3 days gap from current date. Also, the weekend should be excluded from the 3 days of gap. I was able to do the first task and lost with the logic to proceed the second. I am aware of using date.getDay() but I am lost for building up the algorithm. Please explain where should I construct.

```
  const addDate = 7;
  const min = new Date(Date.now() +  (addDate * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
  
  const year = min.getFullYear();
  const month = (min.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  const day = min.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  
  //const weekend = min.getDay();
  //console.log("weekend is "+weekend);

  const minDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
  document.getElementById("dateAve").setAttribute("min", minDate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it.

I explained my reasoning as comments in the code

```js
let datesAdded = 0; // For keeping track of the number of times we've changed the date
const maxDatesToAdd = 3; // Number of extra days you want to add to today
const weekends = [0, 6]; // indices of weekends you get from Date.getDay();
let date = new Date();

console.log(`Today: ${date}`);

while (datesAdded < maxDatesToAdd) {
    const newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    
    date = newDate; // Changing the date to newDate
    if (weekends.includes(newDate.getDay())) continue; // Checking if the day we've added is a weekend
    datesAdded++; // Incrementing if the day isnt a weekday and for the while loop to eventually break
}
console.log(`3 days from today without weekends: ${date}`);

const year = date.getFullYear();
const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const minDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`; // Converting the date to a the YYYY-MM-DD format.
console.log(minDate);
```

Comment: as per this, if you set the PC's time to a friday, The browser is keep on loading. Any solution?

Comment: My bad... i've sorted it out though

Comment: if the date includes weekends it returns the same value. date = newDate, because of that?

Comment: I’m trying to save an edit... I’m having really bad connection

Comment: I didn’t see you on GitHub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229974/discussion-between-roshan-zaid-and-a-mola).

Comment: YOU ARE THE PERSON :D